# Mifare 4Kb - Set - Reset - Retrieve authentication block

Tags: c#, winapi, mifare, smartcard-reader

I've mifare 4Kb and recently I wrote a simple .NET (C#) wrapper in order to execute I/O operation through smartcard reader on my mifare cards.

Firt one: is there some API to set-reset key A/B for sector authentication?

Second one: is there some API to retrieve a previous key (A/B) setted that I did forget? (I don't think there is, because if true it should be really ridicolous in security terms!).

Answer (score 1):

Mfoc can restore all keys if you know at least one (or at least one key is default) https://code.google.com/p/mfoc/